# How to find the indices of Tensor A's elements in another Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say we have

```
a = tf.constant(['a', 'c'])
b = tf.constant(['a', 'd', 'c'])
>>> Intended output: [0, 2] since b[0] = a[0] and b[2] = a[1]
```

How to find the positions of a in b?

I think the desired operation is the reverse/inverse of `tf.gather()`.

I know a very space-consuming solution:

```
tf.where(tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(a, 1), tf.expand_dims(b, 0)))[:, 1]  >> array([0, 2])
```

But I think `tf.equal()` will produce a tensor of shape (2, 3). It takes too much space. (space O(m * n) is too much in my case. )

Is there any better solution to save space?

Comment: Could you elaborate more by what you meant by "too much space"?

Comment: @velociraptor11 if tensor a has size m, tensor b has size n. The solution in the question takes O(m * n) space. Is there any way consuming O(m) or O(n) space?

Answer (score 0):

To trade time for space:

```
result = tf.where(tf.equal(b, a[0]))
t = tf.constant(1)

cond = lambda t, result: tf.less(t, tf.shape(a)[0])
body = lambda t, result: [t + 1, tf.concat([result, tf.where(tf.equal(b, a[t]))], axis=0)]
result = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [t, result], shape_invariants=[t.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None, None])])[1]

sess.run(tf.squeeze(result))
```

if tensor a has size m and tensor b has size n, this solution loops for m times and takes O(m*n) time and O(m+n) space.